# ASP.NET MVC4 Query By Example Open Source Suggestions

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1, query-by-example

We're currently building a new application and part of the functionality we want to include for users is the ability to build ad-hoc querys through the web UI for reporting purposes.

e.g. The user may select the Entity1 report.

They are then able to select the criteria through the UI

pseudo example:
((Entity1.Type = 'this' OR Entity1.Type = 'something else') AND Entity1.CreatedDate > '01-01'2012')

Does anyone know if there is a good solution available (open source or paid) as this seems like it might be a lot of work to implement a bespoke solution.

Further to this we are using Entity Framework v4.1 magical unicorn edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use http://devtools.korzh.com/query-builder-aspnet/ as it has saved me a lot of development time.

Answer (score 2):

If you build a UI that gives results in a structured form (e.g. {entityType.property}{operation}{value}) then it should be fairly straightforward to dynamically build an expression for this.